# How do I make Firefox console group repeat outputs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition, firefox-quantum

I recently switched to Firefox Quantum Developer from Chrome and I notice that duplicate log messages aren't collapsed like they are in Chrome:

[image: Ungrouped Firefox DevTools console output]

How would I make this all show as one, like this

[image: Grouped Chrome DevTools console output]

Edit: It seems that it does this for some outputs but not others, which I find strange.

Comment: I'm interested in the OPPOSITE.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools console generally groups output.

For example, executing the code of your screenshot shows this:
[image: Grouped Firefox DevTools console output]

Though, when you output objects it may happen that they are not grouped. If that's the case, check if the data is really identical (incl. source links). It may be that your output refers to different objects. E.g.

```
for(let i=0;i<100;i++) { console.log(["test"]); }
```

will output 100 times `Array [ "test" ]`.

If you're sure your output refers to identical objects, ensure you have the latest version of Firefox installed. If it still occurs in the current version of Firefox, you should [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console).